# How can I extract or cut html contents of inside <div id="mainContent" ......> ........ </div>? The html source is not correctly formatted

Tags: php, regex, parsing, html-parsing

```
<html>
    <head><title>bla bla</title></head>
    <body>
    <div id="mainContent" xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        bla bla .....
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to extract that division. How can I do it using PHP 5?

The html source is not currectly formatted. There are some undefined attributes.

Comment: Document Class will be helpfull here

Comment: You do NOT want to use a regex for this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: But that html source string is not correctly formated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your HTML is not well formed, you can still use stuff like `DOMDocument`, e.g.:

```
$d = new DOMDocument;
$d->loadHTML($htmlstring);

$x = new DomXPath($d);

foreach ($x->query('//div[@id="mainContent"]') as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Alternatively, just prefix the HTML with `<!DOCTYPE html>` so that you can use `getElementById` as per normal.

Answer (score 0):

`/<div id=\"mainContent\".*?</div>/gs`

http://regexr.com?30o0l if you want to capture everything from the div opening tag to the closing tag.

Comment: This will match anything tile the **last** closing tag. It will work only for this very simple example.